# OpenGL Palette Swap shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, palette

I'm coding a fighting game in which each character has a great number of sprites, and each character has several different palette swaps. I've been trying to use a grayscale texture for each sprite, and a 256x1 texture for each palette.

My shaders look like this:

Vertex:

```
varying vec2 coord;
void main(void)
{
    coord = gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

Fragment:

```
uniform sampler2D palette;
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying vec2 coord;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(palette, vec2(texture2D(texture, coord).r, 0));
}
```

"palette" is set to 1 and "texture" is set to 0 with glGetUniformLocation and glUniform1i. They compile fine and link fine. I'm able to use the program object in my draw code.

The problem is, I have no idea how to use multitexturing to get the "palette" and "texture" textures cooperating with each other in the shader. This is my first time using multitexturing, and I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work for this kind of solution. Does anyone know how, with these shaders (if they are correct) to simulate a palette swap?

EDIT: Here's my drawing code right now:

```
glUseProgram(paletteProgram);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, palette);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(w1, h1);
glVertex3f(x1, y1, 0);
glTexCoord2f(w1, h2);
glVertex3f(x1, y2, 0);
glTexCoord2f(w2, h2);
glVertex3f(x2, y2, 0);
glTexCoord2f(w2, h1);
glVertex3f(x2, y1, 0);
glEnd();

glUseProgram(0);
```

Comment: Your code seems correct (except for glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) which doesn't have any effect when you're using a shader, should remove it). Have you independently verified that these textures are loaded and can be sampled correctly, all multitexturing aside?

Comment: Yes, I've tested both textures, and they both work correctly independently without the shader.

Comment: Hmm I'm stumped. Anyway all I can suggest is to check glGetError if you haven't, and also to check the shader infologs (perhaps theres some kind of non-fatal warning there that could give a clue).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is that it is unable to sample from the palette texture, or whatever is in GL_TEXTURE1. But I can't figure out exactly why...

Comment: How did you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: If I make the palette GL_TEXTURE0, I can sample from it perfectly, but I can't sample from the actual sprite. If I make it GL_TEXTURE1, I can't sample from it, but I can sample from the sprite.

Comment: All I can suggest is to put up all of your OGL code (shader init, uniform initialization, etc). I don't think there's anything wrong in what you've posted so far. Maybe a mistake is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems sound. What you need to do is to set the active texture using [glActiveTexture](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glActiveTexture.xml) and then bind your texture as usual (for texture units 0 and 1). Now also bind the values 0 to the uniform called texture and 1 to the uniform called palette.

Inside GLSL, you can then use texture2D to fetch texels from the appropriate sampler.

Hope this helps!

This is actually explained in detail over here in [this](http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/glsl_an_introduction/25007/) NeHe tutorial (section: Using textures with GLSL).

This is what you need to do

```
    glUseProgramObject(my_program);
    int my_sampler_uniform_location = glGetUniformLocation(my_program, my_color_texture);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, my_texture_object);

    glUniform1i(my_sampler_uniform_location, i);
```

Comment: May I have a code example? I thought I was doing this, but the result is always just a solid black texture.

Comment: Check the Nehe link. It is explained with code and sample in there.

Comment: @MathewVelasquez you should post your own code, so that we can see if there's something wrong with it, instead of asking for someone else to write it.

Comment: Whoa, whoa. Where's the glUniform (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml) call where you set the sampler on the shader to the texture unit?

Answer (score -2):

Okay, I figured it out!

Apparently the uniform variables are reset every time the script program is used... I just needed to set them every frame.

I feel so stupid now, but hey, that's what debugging is.

Comment: That shouldn't happen; the uniforms are supposed to persist indefinitely, you shouldn't have to overwrite them every frame. Maybe your initialization is failing for some reason, or you're accidentally overwriting it somewhere else?